# How to fix an outline?

Tags: materials

I don’t know why but from some angles the outline starts to look really bad
And I don’t know what the reason is
[image]
[image]
[image]
How to fix it?

Comment: Where the outline starts to look really bad? Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.